# Excel Vlookup formula for pivot table reference

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a nutrition database pivot table on one sheet and a meal planner on the other. When I enter the food I want to reference the other cells to lookup it's values from the pivot table. I can do this but my problem is that if I add more columns to the table it's all out of sync.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C7,NutritionDatabase,6,FALSE),0)
```

If I enter the food into C7, I'm currently using this formula above to lookup the kcals per 100g in the 6th column of my NutritionDatabase pivot table.

Is there any way to lookup the column title and reference the data from the same row as the food in C7. NutritionDatabase[[#This Row],[Kcalsp100]]

Something along the lines of this below but except this doesn't work?

```
=VLOOKUP($C7,NutritionDatabase[[#This Row],[Kcalsp100]],FALSE)
```

Would you be able to offer any experience and tips, please?

This would be very useful because in the future I want to expand the NutritionDatabase by adding more data and columns, if I'm referencing the column number then I'm going to have to change everything when I do that.

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It would help to see how your data is laid out but you should be able to use Match to return the required column number. For the row part, it would help to see some data and expected result.

Comment: Thanks. I've added images to the my OP. Hope that helps show the data.

Comment: Looks like someone has run with Match as an answer so you can see that bit. Can you explain more about why you need this row part? Will it not suffice to have VLOOKUP with match to get the right header column and use relative address for lookup value.

Comment: In the nutrition database, I am hoping to add more columns for example next to Protienp100g at column G I might add 'Amino Acids' or next to Carbsper100 I might add Fibre.
However, if my Vlookup is currently set to reference col_index_num then my lookup will be off because I would have moved the columns around the the column number might not always be 6. I was just hoping I could reference the title so that If I moved the columns around then all my formulas would still work.

Comment: If your first column physically has the same address the solution given should work for getting correct column. You just need to ensure Match uses the correct row. If the row can change then you will need a two-way lookup. Can the row change for the headers? If so what is a distinct column header that will only occur once on the page?

Comment: @Ross That is what the MATCH function does, It looks for the correct column header and then returns the `col_index_num` for that column. So you can add new columns and `col_index_num` will move along with it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand that now. But I can't seem to get the provided =vlookup and match formula to work -> it just opens a file explorer window 'Update Values: NutritionDatabase' and results #N/A -  So yes in theory I dropdown the food in $C7 and it spits out the values from FGHI  Kcalsp100 Proteinp100 Carbsp100 Fatp100

Comment: '=IVLOOKUP($C7,NutritionDatabase,MATCH($G6,NutritionDatabase[#Headers],0),FALSE)' - Got it to work using this. Excel give me [#Headers] by clicking stuff and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the MATCH function for you `col_index_num` in you VLOOKUP:

`=MATCH (lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])`

More information: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-match-function

**MATCH Function:**

`MATCH("Kcalsp100",NutritionDatabase!$A1:$A15,1)`

What this will do is match the lookup value again the first row, column headers, and return a index (number of the column) for the column with the matching name.

**LOOKUP Function:**

`=VLOOKUP($C7,NutritionDatabase!$A1:$E15,MATCH("Kcalsp100",NutritionDatabase!$A1:$A15,1),FALSE)`

EDIT:

Looking at the new images try something alone the lines of

`=VLOOKUP($C7, NutritionDatabase!$A2:$I6,MATCH($F6, NutritionDatabase!$A2:$I2,1),FALSE)`

You may have to change the two `NutritionDatabase` ranges to match you scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using INDEX-MATCH-MATCH. It is much, much faster that VLOOKUP (probably not that important for your use case, but for large amounts of data, it's a must), and it's more adaptable.

It is used in the form:

```
=INDEX(<LookUpRange>, MATCH(<RowValToFind>,<RowRange>,0), MATCH(<ColValToFind>,<ColRange>,0))
```

So, in cell F7 of your meal plan sheet you could use:

```
 =INDEX(NutritionDatabase!$F$3:$I$6, MATCH($C7,NutritionDatabase!$A$3:$A$6,0), MATCH(F$6,NutritionDatabase!$F$2:$I$2,0))
```

I know this looks complicated to begin with, but when you break it down, it's no too bad and much faster and more versatile than VLOOKUP.

Basically, it is saying:

```
=INDEX(<get the value from in this table where...>, MATCH(<this value appears in...>, <this list of row headers and...>,0), MATCH(<this value appears in...>, <this list of column headers>, 0))
```

Not that the 0's in the match indicate that it should be an exact match.

Here is an image of another, simple example:

[image]